# Installing ubuntu 20.04 and it crashes during or after profile setup

Tags: partitioning, scripts, ssd, crash

I am doing a fresh install of Ubuntu server 20.04 on an AMD Ryzen 9 9350 570 series motherboard with 32GB ram and 2TB PCIe M.2 2TB SSD and every time I get to the profile setup it crashes.

If I install 20.04 desktop it installs fine but will not install libraries or dependencies what can I do is it the SSD?

```
    *-firmware                
   description: BIOS
   vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: 2607
   date: 08/14/2020
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 31
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 64GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3333 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: TEAMGROUP-UD4-3200
          vendor: Team Group Inc.
          physical id: 0
          serial: 01A40949
          slot: DIMM_A1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3333MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3333 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/16GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 1EC27CB3
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3333MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3333 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: TEAMGROUP-UD4-3200
          vendor: Team Group Inc.
          physical id: 2
          serial: 01A40973
          slot: DIMM_B1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3333MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3333 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/16GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: 50C28B79
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3333MHz (0.3ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 34
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 35
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 36
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 64MiB
       capacity: 64MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Comment: Ryzen processor have notorious memory issues. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: why would it install the GUI and not the CLI wouldn't the GUI require more uses of ram

Comment: You're having problems with BOTH server and desktop versions. Did you run `memtest` yet?

Comment: But... did you run `memtest`?

Comment: sorry doing it tonight

Comment: So test completed and passed 100%

Comment: Good! You ran all 4/4 tests, correct? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: sudo lshw -C memory shows alot what are you looking for

Comment: Yes, the `sudo lshw -C memory` does show a lot. Copy the output to the clipboard, edit your answer, paste it in at the end, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format it into human-readable. I'm looking to see that your memory is install correctly. Also, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Thanks.

Comment: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version  2607

Comment: Thanks for the info... however... I gave instructions on how to add all of that data to your original question. When placed into the comments, it's impossible to read/decipher. Your BIOS is 2607, but you forgot to tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Please retry.

Comment: {my fault i was rrushing the motherboard is ASUS X570-PLUS WIFI BIOS 2607}

Comment: Your BIOS is up to date. I made a temporary answer to show you where the {} is. Please redo the `sudo lshw -C memory` command for me, and then delete the 5 comments that contain that same data. Thanks.

Comment: done i added it

Comment: 1) Thanks for the info, the configuration looks correct, however 2) you didn't follow my instructions to add that info to your original question, but rather you put that data into a new answer, and 3) you didn't delete the 5 comments that contained that information. So now that I've seen that info, please delete that answer, and the 5 comments, for me. Thanks.